# AHK How to pass variables to "Run" inside a function?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm fairly new to autohotkey and ran into a problem recently when trying to pass variables as parameters for the "run" command in autohotkey. Can anyone show me what I'm missing or is this a bug?

```
Gui, Setup:Add, Edit, w100 vProgram
Gui, Setup:Add, Button, Default w100 gSubmit, OK
Gui, Setup:Show,, Setup
WinWaitClose, Setup
ExitApp

Submit:
    Gui, Setup:Submit
    RunStuff()

RunStuff() {
    Run, %Program%
}
```

I've even tried changing the line to this:

```
RunStuff() {
    run, Program
}
```

I would really appreciate the help, thanks in advance.

Comment: If your program path has spaces you'll need quotes around it: `Run, "%Program%"`

Comment: It does not, and when adding quotes it opens the file navigation manager(explorer.exe). Originally I wanted to run something like: “run, notepad.exe %args%”

Comment: When using “msgbox, %program%” the variable appears but when using “run, %program%” the variable is blank

Comment: Can you provide some sample strings you'd want to run? In any case, everything does work fine when done correctly. Different to the other comment above though, I'd recommend to use the expression syntax.

Comment: Of course, I’ve tested with “cmd.exe”, “notepad.exe” but what I was originally trying to do is this “run, netsh wlan connect said=%networkname% name=%networkname%” none of these worked with or without spaces

Comment: Ok, so the problem is the the edit is returning nothing, how can I fix this

Comment: your variable is global, try to add `global Program` line inside your function, otherwise it treats it as local, so it is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, while

```
WinWaitClose, Setup
ExitApp
```

Is maybe smart thinking, you're supposed to do this with the [`GuiClose` event](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#GuiClose) by just defining a function (or a label) with the name `GuiClose`.

```
GuiClose()
{
    ExitApp
}
```

Also, giving the gui a name is redundant, although if you're planning on adding more guis, fair enough.

And to run cmd commands, you'd start off cmd with the `/c`<sup>[(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd#parameters)</sup> switch.
Your example `netsh wlan connect ssid=%networkname% name=%networkname%` would be done like this:

```
networkname := "name"
Run, %A_ComSpec% /c netsh wlan connect ssid=%networkname% name=%networkname%
Run, % A_ComSpec " /c netsh wlan connect ssid=" networkname " name=" networkname
```

The first line is in legacy syntax, I wouldn't really recommend it.
The second line is in expression syntax.

The built in variable `A_ComSpec`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ComSpec)</sup> contains the path to cmd.exe.

Example program based on your code to open a file in notepad:

```
Gui, Setup:Add, Edit, w300 vFilePath, % "C:\Users\User\Desktop\this is a text file.txt"
Gui, Setup:Add, Button, Default w100 gSubmit, OK
Gui, Setup:Show, , Setup
return

Submit:
    Gui, Setup:Submit
    Run, % "notepad.exe """ FilePath """"
return

GuiClose()
{
    ExitApp
}
```

Note how the file path includes spaces, so the argument needs to wrapped in quotes.
`""""` may seem weird, but a quote is [escaped](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm) with another quote in AHK. So outer quotes specify that you're writing the string, and inner `""` is just one quote escaped. So this produces `"`.

Legacy syntax vs modern expression syntax can be a bit confusing when you're learning AHK. You'll see a lot of legacy syntax when you look up stuff. This is mainly because AHK was much more popular years and years ago (when legacy syntax was the thing to use).
To get started off on the legacy vs modern expression differences, here's a pretty good documentation page:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm

---

EDIT:
Answer to the new problem that as added in via an edit to the OP.

```
RunStuff() {
    Run, %Program%
}
```

The variable `Program` is not defined in the function's scope.

Lets consider this example code

```
var1        := 1
var2        := 2
global var3 := 3
function()
return

function()
{
    global var2
    MsgBox, % "var1: " var1 "`nvar2: " var2 "`nvar3: " var3 "`n"
}
```

`var1` is not defined in the function's scope, so nothing will be printed in the message box.
`var2` will be used from outside the function's scope because of the line `global var2`.
`var3` would also be used from outside of the function scope because var3 was defined as super global. Super global isn't really recommended, because anything anywhere will use that variable then. Quite easy to run into problems on larger scripts, but it's convenient for smaller scripts where you know what you'll be doing and don't have any external libraries for example.
You can read the related documentation from here:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Locals

Comment: First of all, you don’t need to run cmd since netsh is an independent program that can be run without cmd, second, is that my problem is the edit in the GUI not giving anything in the output variable.

Comment: Right, didn't know it's a program. You can skip cmd then. And the variable is just fine unless your code is something other than the code you've shown.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am trying to get the text of the edit from a function which doesn't work

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the Edit's information from a function, I assume I would have to make it global somehow?

Comment: Yes, scopes would be your problem then. I'll edit my answer to include info about that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you think your problem is with the gui output.

I think you might want to check things in a different way:

You could create a script to analyze the your run inputs.

For example:

Script #1, let's call it "1.ahk"

```
Run, 2.ahk param1 param 2 "param 3"
```

Script #2, let's call it "2.ahk"

```
txt := "Params as seen by ahk:`n"
for i, param in A_Args
    txt .= i " = " param "`n"
MsgBox % txt
```

By running script "1.ahk" you can see the message that "2.ahk" creates:

```
Params as seen by ahk:
1 = param1
2 = param
3 = 2
4 = param 3
```

Which I think it's quite telling about how it understands spaces, and how quotes prevent splitting arguments.

Now if you run your gui outputs against "2.ahk" you might see something different to what you saw before.

Answer (score 0):

```
RunStuff() {
    Run % start "" "C:\blabla\prog.exe" -windowstyle minimized
}
```